# Fixed navbar hides web content and JS is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is what happen when I press the button "Contacto"

[image]

and should be like this

[image]

and now I'm using this javascript code

```
    $(function(){
    $('a#boton-contacto').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var strAncla = $(this).attr('href');

        $('body,html').stop(true ,true).animate({
            scrollTop: $(strAncla).offset().top - $('nav').height()
        }, 500);

    });
});
```

but it made the button stop working, I want to know why, what is wrong?

you can go to my site and try it http://genebi.net I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: If you turn on your console in your browser (or use Firebug), you'll see that there's an issue with your jQuery code.  The var `strAncla` contains *genebi.net/#contacto*, which is not a valid jQuery selector (which you try to use in your `scrollTop: $(strAncla)...`)

Comment: You are right, i didn't notice that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code from you jQuery:

`var strAncla = $(this).attr('href');` is setting `strAncla` to be "http://genebi.net/#contacto"

And since "http://genebi.net/#contacto" is not a valid selector, there is a javascript error that prevents the code from running.

To solve this, either:

1. Change your url for the element from:
   `<a id="boton-contacto" href="http://genebi.net/#contacto">CONTACTO</a>`

to `<a id="boton-contacto" href="http://genebi.net/#contacto">CONTACTO</a>`

or:

2: You could use a data attribute in your link:

`<a id="boton-contacto" href="http://genebi.net/#contacto" data-element="#contacto">CONTACTO</a>`

and alter your jQuery as follows:

`var strAncla = $(this).attr('data-element');`

And it will work as you desire.

Comment: I solved my problem, but thank you for your answer it is a nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed;` removes it from the normal flow of the document, and means that it doesn't occupy space. You can fix this without Javascript (and it'll be much less janky). It's a little awkward to work around this, but you can do it by having a blank div underneath it to fill up the space. Let's call it "header-spacer".

```
<div class="header">
  ...
</div>
<div class="header-spacer"></div>
```

And some CSS:

```
.header-spacer {
    height: 70px;
}
```